# Jmeter_home environment variable is not defined correctly in Jenkins only ,works fine with cmd prompt

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to integrate `jmeter` with Jenkins and when I try to execute getting `jmeter_home` env variable, is not defined correctly. It works perfectly when try to execute through the command prompt.

Tried multiple options of setting `jmeter_home` in Jenkins config global as `~/.jmeter`.

Changing `jmeter` path in system and through a couple of options but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. The environment variable name is case-sensitive, it needs to be `JMETER_HOME`
2. Tilda resolves to `$HOME` environment variable in shell, it might be the case [it isn't set](https://superuser.com/a/271935/283863) so in that case you might want to use full path or check your OS configuration

In general as [per JMETER_HOME variable description](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter#L44)

> (Optional) May point to your JMeter install dir. If empty
> it will be set relativ to this script.

So you don't have to pass it, JMeter will "guess" its home from the [`jmeter` starup script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter) location

Also remember that you can always launch [JMeter .jar file directly](https://www.baeldung.com/java-run-jar-with-arguments) as:

```
java -jar /path/to/ApacheJMeter.jar
```

And last but not the least you may find [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article useful